# Warning about deprecated findDOMNode when using react-router-navigation-prompt

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am using react-router-navigation-prompt to show a modal window when a user is leaving the page. It works fine, however after updating my dependencies i keep getting this error:
[image: findDOMNode]

I've tried to forward ref to the child component but It didn't seem to work. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import NavigationPrompt from 'react-router-navigation-prompt';
import { CancelChangesDialog } from './CancelChangesDialog';
import _ from 'lodash';

interface Props<T> {
  currentForm: T;
  initialForm: T;
}

export function LeavingPrompt<T>(props: Props<T>) {
  const { currentForm, initialForm } = props;

  return (
    <NavigationPrompt when={!_.isEqual(currentForm, initialForm)}>
      {({ onConfirm, onCancel }) => (
        <CancelChangesDialog
          open
          handleCancel={onCancel}
          handleConfirm={onConfirm}
        />
      )}
    </NavigationPrompt>
  );
}
```

CancelChangesDialog Is the modal view component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogContent,
  DialogContentText,
  DialogActions,
  Button,
} from '@material-ui/core';

interface Props {
  open: boolean;
  handleCancel(): void;
  handleConfirm(): void;
}

export function CancelChangesDialog(props: Props) {
  const { open, handleCancel, handleConfirm } = props;

  return (
    <Dialog open={open}>
      <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">{'Confirm changes'}</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent>
        <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
          Changes are not saved! Leave anyway?
        </DialogContentText>
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button onClick={handleCancel} color="primary">
          Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button
          onClick={handleConfirm}
          color="primary"
          style={{ textTransform: 'initial' }}
          autoFocus
        >
          Confirm
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
}
```

Any Ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Issue tracker reference: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13394
There are a few options:

1. Partially disable strict mode: `<Dialog disableStrictModeCompat>`
2. It has been converted over to use refs in an [unstable theme](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/#unstable-createmuistrictmodetheme-options-args-theme) in @material-ui/core@^4.10:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { unstable_createMuiStrictModeTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
const theme = unstable_createMuiStrictModeTheme();
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
<Dialog>...</Dialog>
</ThemeProvider>
```

Note: Read the documentation for the unstable theme.  There are limitations.

Codesandbox demo of fix:
https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-gould-j7pqu

[Reason:](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13221#issuecomment-429451615)

> The API allows in many cases that users pass a custom root component. We still need findDOMNode if those components don't forward their refs properly.